# Pass 4x4 matrix to a shader cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, shader, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to pass  my own mvp matrix which is float 4x4 to a vertex shader, but I'm always getting OpenGL error 0x0501 which is meant that passing value is incompatible with the receiver variable.

here's the code of the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec4 a_posL;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mvp_matrix * a_posL;
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

here's my custom matrix:

```
struct Matrix4f {
    float m[4][4];
};
```

here's the initialization of matrix:

```
float x = 0.1f;
    m_translateMatrix.m[0][0] = 1.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[0][1] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[0][2] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[0][3] = 0.0f;
    m_translateMatrix.m[1][0] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[1][1] = 1.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[1][2] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[1][3] = 0.0f;
    m_translateMatrix.m[2][0] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[2][1] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[2][2] = 1.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[2][3] = 0.0f;
    m_translateMatrix.m[3][0] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[3][1] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[3][2] = 0.0f; m_translateMatrix.m[3][3] = 1.0f;
```

and here's the way I'm passing my brand-new matrix to the shader:

glUseProgram(m_shaderProgram->program);

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBufferId);

    GLint posAttr = glGetAttribLocation(m_shaderProgram->program, "a_posL");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttr);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttr, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);

    GLuint mat_loc = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram->program, "mvp_matrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mat_loc, 1, GL_TRUE, &m_translateMatrix.m[0][0]);


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)m_trianglesData.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, m_trianglesData.data());

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    CHECK_GL_ERROR_DEBUG();
```

What can I do wrong?

P.S.: Yes, I know that cocos2d-x already has all the matrices I need, but my main goal is to get how it works by myself without any cocos solutions. And I'm using cocos2d-x only because it already has opengl window where I can draw and I know to understand **all** options in using OpenGL with that engine.

Comment: Have you verified that the error was not caused by something else? That is, when you remove all references to the 4x4 matrix both in the shader and the objective C side, does everything render as usual?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yeah, it works perfectly without matrix. Problems start when I implemented matrix.

Comment: What version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: Hello Reto, thank you for answer! I think it's OpenGL 2.0.DO you think I might be using some deprecated methods?